# Get primary key I just inserted with Spring

Tags: mysql, spring

Im inserting a row in a table in MySQL. this is the code:

```
public final String SQLADDPROJECT="insert into table(value1,value2,value3) values(?,?,?)";
getJdbcTemplate().update(SQLADDPROJECT, new Object[]{model.getValue1, 
            model.getValue2(),
            model.getValue3()});
```

This insert statement works ok, the model is not null. The table has a primary key that is autoincremental, and I would like to get that key, so I can use it later in code. I've done some search, and used a keyHolder, this way:

```
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
public final String SQLADDPROJECT="insert into table(value1,value2,value3) values(?,?,?)";
getJdbcTemplate().update(SQLADDPROJECT, new Object[]{model.getValue1, 
            model.getValue2(),
            model.getValue3()}, keyHolder);
Long pk=keyHolder.getKey().longValue();
```

But Im receiving an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setSerializableObject(PreparedStatement.java:3920)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:3564)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:816)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
my.package.Dao.ProyectoDaoImp.saveProject(ProyectoDaoImp.java:54)
my.package.Services.ProyectoServiceImp.saveProject(ProyectoServiceImp.java:25)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:109)
org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:155)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:193)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

causa raíz

java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setSerializableObject(PreparedStatement.java:3909)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:3564)
   org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:816)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
my.package.Dao.ProyectoDaoImp.saveProject(ProyectoDaoImp.java:54)
my.package.Services.ProyectoServiceImp.saveProject(ProyectoServiceImp.java:25)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:109)
org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:155)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:193)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Can I use KeyHolder this way? if not, how can I get the pk I just inserted? thank you.

Note: My class extends JdbcDaoSupport

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen example around where they use a `KeyHolder` but I found that too much bother when there is a much simpler method available. I've literally done it this morning. You use a `SimpleJdbcInsert` object and it will return out the generated key.

```
SimpleJdbcInsert insertContactList = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate)
            .withTableName("FOO_TABLE").usingColumns("Other", "Columns")
            .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("FooID");

Map<String,Object> insertParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
/* 
 * These key pair values must match the columns that you 
 * specified in the .usingColumns() call above. If you don't
 * want to insert any other data, just don't call the .usingColumns method,
 * and insert a blank map.
 */ 
insertParameters.put("Other", foo.getOther());
insertParameters.put("Columns", foo.getColumns());

Number generatedFooId = insertContactList.executeAndReturnKey(insertParameters);
return generatedFooId;
```

This method is obviously assuming that you have a `JdbcTemplate` available, and that your PK is a database generated value.

If any of this is unclear tell me and I can expand my answer.

Comment: Im trying it out, when I see if it works Ill give feedback to you. Thanks!

Comment: worked nice, thank you! If someones uses this answer, and has any "BINARY" field in his Database, and using it as "true" or "false", if you do "insertparameters.put("Other", true); it will launch a DataTruncationException. You must do "insertParameters.put("Other", 1)"

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no method in `JdbcTemplate` with `update(String sql, Object[] args, KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder)` arguments.

You only have `update(PreparedStatementCreator psc, KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder)`

Your method call is invoking one of the overloaded method `update(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes)` which is causing `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value:`

Comment: I know, but there is a method with the signature update(String sql, Object... args) which means that you can add to the method any number of arguments of any type. I thought it could work adding the KeyHolder, but it does not.